# I hope you can help me in this matter // is it correct?

Tags: business-language, letter-writing, verb-forms

I am writing a letter to the company with attached CV.
This company can manage accreditation process and provide world leading task management and support for a specific type of job.

In the end of my letter I am planning to use:
......
***I hope you can help in this matter.
Looking forward to receiving your reply.
Thank you.
MyName***

or better in such way:

......
***Kindly advise if you can help and assist in my matter?
Looking forward to receiving your reply.
Thank you.
MyNam***e

Please suggest better business language form, or both of them are acceptable ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to it as a matter is a way of separating it from you. This "matter" is your passion, not a distant subject but close and dear to you.

Asking if they can help in this matter is correct in that it describes at a polite distance their capacity and perhaps willingness to help. You are hoping they can help but at such a distance that you are not pleading to them. That would be unprofessional to say nothing of embarrassing to them. The first sentence is OK.

The second is a bit more personal in that you are calling the matter "Mine" and it is All Wrong in that you are using the distancing term "matter" with the imperative of mine. It is your passion, not your matter. The mixing of a possessive tone with the objective description is unexpected and jarring. Others will have a more accurate etymology of these terms but it is not right. The term "Kindly advise" also sounds peculiar in a bad way. Better would be "Please advise" which is polite and at a respectable distance.

A proper phrasing could be "Please let me know if you can help in this matter." Here the term "this" is keeping the matter at a distance, just as "matter" does,  which is what you are seeking for a professional tone.

Also, use either assist or help, not both as it dilutes the focus of the sentence. "if you can do something, anything, really anything at all.." only makes a point of your desperation. You want clear, direct and brief communication. Too bad I've not been able to do the same.